# JS: Scope Inside Constructor Function

Tags: javascript, oop, constructor

I am new to OOP and I am trying to rewrite a simple JS function as an object literal and then as a constructor function. I succeeded in writing the object literal version, but I clearly have a scope problem inside the anon function which handles the onclick event (inside my constructor function). Please let me know how to make the onclick event work.

Object Literal Version Which WORKS:

```
var submit = {
    form_id : "",   
    submit_button_id : "",
    submit_form: function(){
        var button = document.getElementById(submit.submit_button_id);
        var form = document.getElementById(submit.form_id);     
        button.onclick = function(){
            form.submit();
            return false;
        }
    }
}

addLoadEvent(function(){
    submit.form_id = "form_vars";
    submit.submit_button_id = "but_submit";
    submit.submit_form();
});
```

Constructor Function Version Which DOESN'T WORK:

```
function SubmitForm(button_id, form_id){
    this.submit_button = document.getElementById(button_id);
    this.form = document.getElementById(form_id);
    this.submit_form = function(){
        // problem function below
        this.submit_button.onclick = function(){
            this.form.submit();
        }
    }
}   

addLoadEvent(function(){
    var form_to_submit = new SubmitForm("but_submit", "form_vars");
    form_to_submit.submit_form();
});
```

P.S. I am aware that I should be using DOM API event handlers instead of HTML-DOM ones. I am just tackling one thing at a time.

Comment: Have you considered using libraries like dojo or jquery?  They simplify OO programming and provide improved event handling over basic javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` inside your function will not necessarily be the same as `this` in the constructor, it is decided by how you call that function. For instance, if you call a function `f` by doing `f()`, then `this === window`, if it is a method on an object `x.f()` then `this === x`. Also see `Function:call` and `Function:apply`.

Simplest way to solve this is to have a local variable in the constructor (like `var me = this;`) and then use `me` instead of `this` in the inner function, since that will not be overridden.

Read up on lexical scoping and closures if you want to learn more.

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you. I will read about lexical scoping and closures.

Comment: Fancy explanation: regular variables are resolved statically, `this` is resolved dynamically :-)

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful. I wasn't trained as a programmer, so I will go and read about the differences between dynamic and static resolving now. Does this mean that "this" makes use of dynamic scoping OR dynamic scoping and resolving things dynamically are unrelated? Btw, I read about closures (and lexical scoping) since your original response and I finally understand what closures do.

Comment: "scope" and "resolution" are related. If something has dynamic scope it is resolved dynamically.